# Implementing the List<Node>

Tags: java, list, dom, nodelist

I decided to implement the Abstract `List<Node>` . here is a piece of it:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    public class myNodeList implements NodeList{


    Node root = null;
    int length = 0;

    public myNodeList() {}   
    public void addNode(Node node) {  
        if(root == null)   
        {
            root = node;  
               }
          else          
         root.appendChild(node);   
        length++;   
        System.out.println("this is the added node " +node);
    }      
     }
```

but when I try to `add` a node, it gives me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.insertBefore(NodeImpl.java:478)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:235)
at pageparsertest.myNodeList.addNode(myNodeList.java:27)
```

is this because of the `Node root = null;` which makes to add a node to a null node?
then how can be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is embarressing but I changed my idea to implement that and instead used`static List<Node> listOfNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();`
 which worked well for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can't append to a `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl`, you'll need to use    `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode`.

`appendChild` will call `insertBefore` which only throws an `Exception` for `NodeImpl`

[Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/NodeImpl.java#NodeImpl.insertBefore%28org.w3c.dom.Node%2Corg.w3c.dom.Node%29)

> Move one or more node(s) to our list of children. Note that this
>   implicitly removes them from their previous parent.
>
> **By default we do not accept any children, ParentNode overrides this**.

Take a look how `Axis` implemented their : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.0.2/org/apache/axis/message/NodeListImpl.java

It seems you're trying to build a Node tree using the first Node as the Root, not a node list. Which is not possible has your nodes are `NodeImpl` not `ParentNode`.

If you want a tree, you'll have to create (or import) somehow a parent node.
If you just need a list, then use a `List`.

---

You may need to create a fake custom parent to insert your nodes.
Take a look here : [HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR while trying to add elements to xml file in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864285/hierarchy-request-err-while-trying-to-add-elements-to-xml-file-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: but it seems he is using **org.w3c.dom.Node**

Comment: I dont know how to do that. what I mean is I cant find out how to use **com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode** and since in the erst of my programs I used **org.w3c.dome.Node** it's kind of making me to use casting and then when I run the program, it denies to allows casting and stuff.

Comment: I just parse the HTML code of a page, then Use ""tagsoup** library to create the DOM from the HTML. then choosing some nodes from that DOM which want to put them in a list for future use, but this problem appears.

Comment: thats what I was trying by declaring **root** in my function. did i do it wrong?

Comment: From your code, the first node you add will be the root. But how do you get that root? Creating it yourself or getting it from somewhere else? From the other question you should use `doc.createElement`

Comment: i didnt quite get what you said just now. did you take a look at the addnode function in my code?

Comment: as I explained,i do some calculation on a page's DOM tree , choose some nodes and then add them to a list by calling that function